# What part of the original section command causes the noindent on the next paragraph, even with a newline?

Tags: macros, sectioning

The following examples allow the second paragraph not not have an indent. I am trying to replicate the effect of the section command, which has the ability to add the "noindent-effect" after the empty line. It is important to me it can be substituted as a single command.

```tex
paragraph

\section*{}

paragraph
```

```tex
paragraph

\noindent
paragraph
```

What does not work is:

```
paragraph

\noindent

paragraph
```

From the definition of startsection it does not become clear to me how this "empty line eating" is achieved.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! In your third example, there is a blank line between the `\noindent` command and the next paragraph. There shouldn't be one.

Comment: Could you please read the question? Because also for this question, your reply does remotely go into the actual question asked.

Comment: @Rmano I already found the \@afterindentfalse but that does only work when the command is placed directly before the next paragraph (similar to noindent). Hence the question remains how the section achieves eating the empty line.

Comment: Yes, I noticed it (this is why I removed it).

Comment: @Skinkie What you are looking for is in `\@afterheading`. It sets `\everypar` to do, among other things, `\if@afterindent\else {\setbox\z@\lastbox}\fi`, which removes the indentation box when `\if@afterindent` is false (the “empty line” is *not* eaten: there is a new paragraph in any case).

Comment: @frougon if you have a full example that could do this trick, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The LaTeX sectioning commands use the `\@afterheading` macro, which does three things:

- it says `\@nobreaktrue`, which is defined as `\global\let\if@nobreak\iftrue` and is used in many places of the LaTeX kernel to prevent a page break: in `\@esphack` which is used at the end of `\label`, `\index`, `\vspace` and other places; in `\protected@write` which is used in most file-writing operations; in `\@item`, which is the basis for `\item`; in `\markboth` and `\markright`, etc.;
- it removes the indentation box when the next paragraph starts if the `\if@afterindent` switch is false;
- it prevents a page break after the first line of the next paragraph (possibly the first item of a list) by temporarily setting `\clubpenalty` to 10000.

The last two are done by modifying `\everypar`, but since this change should be in effect only for the next paragraph, the `\if@nobreak` switch is used  to implement “one-shot“ behavior.

## Manual method using `\everypar` directly

The following example implements the “remove the indentation box of the next paragraph” part in macro `\removeNextIndent`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newtoks\my@saved@everypar

\newcommand*{\my@removeIndentBox}{{\setbox\z@\lastbox}}

\newcommand*{\removeNextIndent}{%
  \my@saved@everypar=\expandafter{\the\everypar}%
  %
  \everypar=\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\my@removeIndentBox
    \the\everypar
    \everypar=\expandafter{\the\my@saved@everypar}% restore previous \everypar
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% \everypar={AAA }% see below
The indentation box of the next paragraph will be removed.%
\removeNextIndent

There we are.

The indentation box is back.

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case you uncomment the `\everypar={AAA }`, the output becomes:

[image]

## Using `\@afterheading`

As @DavidCarlisle [mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604643/what-part-of-the-original-section-command-causes-the-noindent-on-the-next-paragr/604652#comment1516396_604652), in case you want all the features of `\@afterheading` (as summarized at the beginning of this answer), the simplest way is to just use it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\removeNextIndentPreventPageBreakEtc}{%
  \par\nobreak % use \vspace here if you want
  \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% \everypar={AAA }% see below
The indentation box of the next paragraph will be removed.%
\removeNextIndentPreventPageBreakEtc

There we are.

The indentation box is back.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that contrary to my manual method above, `\@afterheading` doesn't try to play nice with existing non-empty `\everypar` settings, so in case you uncomment the `\everypar={AAA }`, the output becomes:

[image]

## Using the `ltpara` paragraph hooks

If you are using a [recent enough preview release](https://www.latex-project.org/news/2021/05/05/latex-dev-2021-2/) of LaTeX (e.g., compile with `pdflatex-dev` if your TeX distribution has updates from 2021-06-01 or later) and only want to remove the indentation box of the next paragraph, the following technique is probably the best. It uses the brand new [`ltpara` hooks](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/ltpara-doc.pdf), which are paragraph hooks added to LaTeX (see the [`lthooks` documentation](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/lthooks-doc.pdf) for general information on the underlying hook framework).

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\removeNextIndent}{%
  \AddToHookNext{para/begin}{\OmitIndent}%
}

\begin{document}

% \everypar={AAA }%
The indentation box of the next paragraph will be removed.%
\removeNextIndent

There we are.

The indentation box is back.

\end{document}
```

The output is the same as in my “manual method” above, including if you uncomment the `\everypar={AAA }` line.

Comment: Awesome :) Added a vspace above it, for the actual rendered result.

Comment: Glad to hear that. I simplified the code a litte bit, since it unconditionally removes the next indentation box (contrary to what we have with the `\if@afterindent` switch, which is tested at the last moment). Also, I put `\my@removeIndentBox` at the very beginning of the new `\everypar` in case the existing `\everypar` would add horizontal material to the paragraph (if `{\setbox\z@\lastbox}` came after that, it could remove something else than the indentation box!).

Comment: don't you almost always want the page break control as well so it's simpler just to use `\@afterheading`  directly?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for your comment. I didn't know what the OP precisely wanted... which is why I started with only a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604643/what-part-of-the-original-section-command-causes-the-noindent-on-the-next-paragr/604652#comment1516294_604643) pointing to `\@afterheading`. :) I've added an example that uses `\@afterheading` directly (second “section” of my answer).

Comment: thanks:-)......